# How to check if my button was clicked in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to call a JavaScript function `test()` when I press enter or I click a button but I don't know how to check if the button was clicked in `test()`.

HTML Code :

```
<input id="data" type="text" name="data" value="" onkeypress="test()" /> 
<button id="button" type="submit" onclick="test()">button</button>
```

JavaScript :

```
function test() {
    let data = document.getElementById("data") ;
    let button = document.getElementById("button") ;
    if(data.onkeypressed = this.event.which === 13 || /*need to check if button was clicked*/) {
         ...
         ...
         ...
}
```

How do I do this in JavaScript ?

Comment: If this is about form validation, you can intercept the form submission like this: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/4cwszf2q/ (both pressing enter and clicking the button trigger the submission)

Comment: If one of the answers provided you with what you needed consider upvoting and/or accepting the answer by clicking on the checkmark to left of it. This removes the question from the answering queues and earns you and the answerer a little bit of reputation. If your question is still unanswered please comment or edit the question accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

You can pass `this` to function and check the `tagName`

```js
function test(e) {
    let data = document.getElementById("data") ;
    let button = document.getElementById("button") ;
    if(data.onkeypressed = this.event.which === 13 || e.tagName === "BUTTON") {
      console.log("button")
    }
}
```

```html
<input id="data" type="text" name="data" value="" onkeypress="test(this)" /> 
        <button id="button" type="submit" onclick="test(this)" >button</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass `this` into `test()` and use it there:

```js
function test(el) {
  let enter = el.id === 'data' && this.event.which === 13;
  console.log(`Called by ${el.id}${enter ? ' and Enter was pressed' : ''}.`);
}
```

```html
<input id="data" type="text" name="data" value="" onkeypress="test(this)" />
<button id="button" type="submit" onclick="test(this)">Button</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the button's `onclick` event handler for that. It will be called every time the button is clicked:

**Edit:** You can also use the input's `onkeydown` event to see if the user pressed enter while the input box was selected.

```js
var data = document.getElementById("data") ;
var button = document.getElementById("button");
button.onclick = function() {
  console.log("clicked!");
  test();
  //do something
}

data.onkeydown = function(e) {
  if(e.keyCode == 13) {
    console.log("ENTER IS PRESSED!");
    this.blur(); //de-selects the textbox
  }
}


function test() {
    //do something
}
```

```html
<input id="data" type="text" name="data" value="" /> 
        <button id="button" type="submit" >button</button>
```